# If-else condition gives me errors in PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I have two websites, each with it's own domain name. On load I have execute a php file that is used on both sites and has the same functionality.

Here is the code of that file:

```
<?php
echo    '1';
if ($_SESSION["template"]=="template1";)
{
    echo    '2';
    if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='A')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/a.php'); 
    else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='B')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/b.php');
    else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='C')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/c.php');
}

else if ($_SESSION["template"]=="template2";)
{
    echo    '3';
    if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='A')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/a.php'); 
    else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='B')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/b.php');
    else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='C')
        echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/c.php');
}
else {

echo 'NO DATA';
}
    echo    '4';

?>
```

On each of the two sites I set a session variable but in the above code it doesn't seem to work as I expect it to.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Remove semicolons from if and else if brackets and check the values of session variable.

Comment: The whole can be done with `echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/' . $_SESSION["template"] . '/' . strtolower($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]) . '.php');`. Also `isset($_SESSION["template"])` & `isset($_REQUEST["cmdAction"])` is required.

Answer (score 1):

remove semicolon from `if()` and `else if()` statement, also add brackets when you using nested if else because it makes someone to understand easier and looks better

```
    <?php
    echo    '1';
    if ($_SESSION["template"]=="template1") 
    {
        echo    '2';
        if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='A')
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/a.php'); 
        } 
        else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='B') 
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/b.php');
        } 
        else if { ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='C') 
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template1/c.php');
        }
    } 
    else if ($_SESSION["template"]=="template2") 
    {
        echo    '3';
        if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='A') 
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/a.php'); 
        } 
        else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='B') 
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/b.php');
        } 
        else if ($_REQUEST["cmdAction"]=='C') 
        {
            echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/template2/c.php');
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO DATA';
    }
    echo    '4';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code I edited my answer. The below code will do exactly the same as your code but requires alot less code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['template']) && isset($_REQUEST['cmdAction'])) {
    echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/images/'.$_SESSION['template'].'/'.strtolower($_REQUEST['cmdAction']).'.php'); 
} else {
    echo 'NO DATA';
}
?>
```